# Networking issue with Jenkins pipeline 'sidecar' container

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am seeing some strange behavior attempting to use the Jenkins 'sidecar container' pattern in a pipeline.  My goal in using the pattern is to create a database container, initialize it with test data and run end-to-end tests on a backend application.  Here's what the stage looks like (some detail is removed):

```
    stage('e2e-test') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.image('mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest').withRun(
                    '--network=test_net ' +
                    '--name mssql_dev ' +
                    '--publish 1433:1433 ' + 
                    '--env SA_PASSWORD=password123 ') {

                    docker.image('node:8.16.0-alpine').inside('--network=test_net') {
                        sh '''
                            ./testms.sh
                            sleep 1d
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This script, testms.sh, runs a simple sql command against the server.  When the script runs in the pipeline, the sql command in it fails with a 'connection refused error'.

The *sleep 1d* command is there to keep the containers running so that I can exec commands inside the inner one.  If I

```
docker exec -it container-id sh
```

I can run the same script (testms.sh) and it works as expected.  I can also run

```
docker exec container-id ./testms.sh
```

and that works as expected also.

Any help appreciated, I'm stumped!

Comment: You have two different networks (`--network=test` on one, and `--network=test_net` on the other). That would cause connection problems, right?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response - that was an error in transcribing the pipeline into this post.  I've corrected the example above and checked that in the actual Jenkinsfile, the same network is used in both places.

Comment: Does `testms.sh` wait for the sql-server to be reachable? The examples in https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ seem to suggest that a little waiting script is often necessary.

Comment: That was it! Needed to wait for the db to come online.  You should put this as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!